# Netsuite How do you link sub-tab on home page to page/category?

Tags: tabs, web, categories, netsuite

I am editing a previously set up company web site with Netsuite. I would appreciate any assistance provided on how to link a presentation sub-tab to the appropriate category/page.  The problem is this: The categories were set up and working great until the previous designer deleted a category. I have since recreated this category (named the same as before) but the presentation sub-tab (side navigation on the home page) does not link to it. The sub-tab currently says the category is no longer available. I have made sure that the category is set up like all of the other functioning categories-this leads me to believe it is something to do with defining the path from the sub-tab to the new category, but I cannot find anywhere to change this. I see where to link the main tabs, but not the sub-tabs coming off them. Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the common.css? Is it just the image that is being shown there because the css is shown?  I have seen an issue with our homepage slider where even though the record is set to inactive, it is still invoked unless commented out on the homepage template.  If you cannot find the category image being listed in the CSS nor in the template, then check the custom tabs on your customization setup - it could be hidden there.  Is your category an image/button or a linked text css property?

Comment: I am not sure-I think the site is set up with a combination of both. I have located images for the first level of menu buttons so I know they are done via image/button.  I have located a couple of CSS files and sitemap, but no images notated for the second level of menu buttons which leads me to believe they may be done thru Netsuite but I cannot find where in Netsuite.

Comment: try (as an Admin)  Setup>Site Builder>Item/Category Templates.  Identify which template is used for the homepage and modify that file to remove the image references (comment them out with <!--  -->).  Otherwise you need to check Setup>Sitebuilder>Tags.  Find the Top_menu tag that references the dropdown menu you wish to remove the category button from.  It should be referenced there for sure if it is not in the common.css nor in the homepage template

Comment: Thanks so much!! Lightweight HeavyHanded